# Como puedo recuperar la sesión individual de un carrito de compras para cada usuario registrado

Tags: php, html

Actualmente realizo un ejercicio de carácter académico en el cual debo de realizar un carrito de compras, pero tengo problemas en cuanto a la comprensión de la lógica respecto a cuando un determinado usuario vuelve a iniciar su sesión en la tienda y pueden ver nuevamente los productos que a seleccionado y ha dejado en el carrito y la orden de compra que realizo previamente.

Agradecería de antemano la ayuda.

Saludos.

Este seria el bloque de código que de consulta de base de datos, y el bucle while que muestra los mismos:

```
<?php

     /*Debe tenerse en cuenta que en este documento están insertados 
        partes de la paginación para la presente consulta de datos*/

        /*-- PAGINACIÓN --*/
        $pagination_size = 12; 

         if(isset($_GET['page'])){     
            if($_GET['page']===1){
                 header('Location:index.php');
            }else{
                $numberPage=$_GET['page'];
            }
        }else{
            $numberPage=1; 
        }


$iniFrom = ($numberPage-1)*$pagination_size; /*Esta variable almacena   el registro de la base de dato desde la cual se va a mostrar en la página*/`
$query_sentence = $pdo_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `productos`");  
$query_sentence->execute();

$num_row = $query_sentence->rowCount();//Conteo de número de filas del   registro.

$total_page = ceil($num_row/$pagination_size);
$data_limit_page = $pdo_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `productos`   LIMIT $iniFrom,$pagination_size");
$data_limit_page->execute();
           
while($product = $data_limit_page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):

?>

<div class="card_buy_container" id="cartBuy">

  <div class="image_product_container">
     <img class="image_product" id="imageProduct" src="<?php echo "assets/cds_shop/" . $product['Directory_image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['Nombre_producto']; ?>"/>
 </div>
                   
<div class="info_container">
<span class="details_name_group"><strong><?php echo $product['Nombre_grupo']; ?></strong></span>  
<span class="details_name_product"><strong><?php echo $product['Nombre_producto']; ?></strong></span>  
<span class="details_edition_product"><?php echo $product['Edicion']; ?></span>  
<span class="details_reference_product"><strong><?php echo "Ref: " . $product['Referencia']; ?></strong></span>  
<span class="details_price_product"><strong><?php echo $product['Precio'] . " €"; ?></strong></span>
</div> 

<form class="form_style" method="POST" action="">
                 
  <input type="hidden" name="imagen" id="imagen"  value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($product['Directory_image'],COD,KEY); ?>"/>

   <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"  value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($product['id_productos'],COD,KEY); ?>"/>

   <input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre"  value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($product['id_usuarios'],COD,KEY); ?>"/>

   <input type="hidden" name="precio" id="precio"  value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($product['Precio'],COD,KEY); ?>"/>

   <input type="hidden" name="cantidad" id="cantidad"  value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt(1,COD,KEY); ?>"/> <!-- Inicialmente el campo cantidad comienza con "1" -->


   <button class="button_view_style" id="buttonBuy" type="submit" 
   name="addSubmit"  value="Agregar">Agregar al carrito</button>

</form>

</div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Este segundo bloque corresponde al archivo de la lógica que emplea el carrito de compra.

```
<?php
   error_reporting(0); 
   

   if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();

   }elseif(isset($_SESSION['userBuy'])){
          return $_SESSION['userBuy']['id_usuarios']; 

   }elseif(isset($_COOKIE['id_extremeMusic'])){
          return $_COOKIE['id_extremeMusic'];

   }else{
      $idTemporal = uniqid(rand(), 1);
          setcookie('id_extremeMusic', $idTemporal);
          return $idTemporal;  
   }
    
    $message="";


      if(isset($_POST['addSubmit'])){
         
        
         switch($_POST['addSubmit']){
               
                                
               /*||||| DESENCRIPTADO DE DATOS CON EL MÉTODO openssl_decrypt DE PHP ||||*/ 
               
               /**/
               case 'Agregar':

                //|||| RECEPCIÓN DE DATOS CON LA SUPER GLOBAL $_POST y Y DESENCRIPTADO EL MÉTODO OPENSSL_DECRYPT |||||||||||||||||*/
                
                /*En esta agrupación de bloques de código se ejecutan dos acciones, mediante la declaración de una condicional if-else; la primera 
                corresponde al desencriptado de datos mediante la función "openssl_decrypt", en donde se mostraran nuevamente los datos sin cumplen
                una condición numérica o de cadena de carácteres mediante el uso de las funciones "is_numeric()" y "is_string()", a su vez se recepcionan
                los datos del formulario de productos de la tienda en donde  mediante la variable superglobal "$_POST" los cuales se alamacenaran en una 
                variable super global $_SESSION['CARRITO'], para luego ser vista desde el carrito del cliente.*/

                
                        /*-- Recepción de datos y desencriptado de datos de la imagen del producto --*/
                        if(is_string(openssl_decrypt($_POST['imagen'],COD,KEY))){
                           $image_item = openssl_decrypt($_POST['imagen'],COD,KEY);
                             //$message.= "Ok, cadena de texto correcta... " . $image_item . "</br>";
                        }else{
                             //$message.= "Uppss, cadena de texto incorrecta... " . $image_item . "</br>";
                        }
                          
                        /*-- Recepción de datos y desencriptado de datos del id del producto --*/ 
                        if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY))){
                           $id_item = openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY);
                             //$message.= "Ok, Id correcto..." . $id_item . "</br>";
                        }else{
                             //$message.= "Uppss, Id incorrecto... " . $id_item . "</br>";  
                        }
                        
                        /*-- Recepción de datos y desencriptado de datos del nombre del producto --*/
                        if(is_string(openssl_decrypt($_POST['nombre'],COD,KEY))){
                           $name_item = openssl_decrypt($_POST['nombre'],COD,KEY); 
                             //$message.= "Ok, Nombre correcto... " . $name_item . "</br>";
                        }else{
                             //$message.= "Uppss, Nombre incorrecto... " . $name_item . "</br>";   
                        }
                        
                        /*-- Recepción de datos y desencriptado del precio del producto --*/
                        if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['precio'],COD,KEY))){
                           $price_item = openssl_decrypt($_POST['precio'],COD,KEY);
                             //$message.= "Ok, Precio correcto..." . $price_item . "</br>";
                        }else{
                             //$message.= "Uppss, Precio incorrecto..." . $price_item . "</br>";
                        }
                        
                        /*-- Recepción de datos y desencriptado de la cantidad del producto --*/ 
                        if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['cantidad'],COD,KEY))){
                            $quantity_item = openssl_decrypt($_POST['cantidad'],COD,KEY);   
                              //$message.= "Ok, cantidad correcta..." . $quantity_item . "</br>";
                        }else{
                              //$message.= "Uppss, cantidad incorrecta..." . $quantity_item . "</br>";
                        }    
                 

                /*||||  MANEJO DE SESSIONES |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||*/

                /* Este apartado corresponde a la sesión del carrito de compras, se enumerarán los pasos a seguir:
                 
                   1. Como primer paso se establece una condicional if-else en donde se declara la variable super global 
                      de sesión "$_SESSION['carrito']".
                      
                     DENTRO DEL IF:

                   2. Dentro del "if" se determina si la variable de sesión existe mediante una validación con la función
                      "isset()". 
                      
                   3. Si esta no existe recuperará los datos mediante el array establecido de nombre "$productsBuy" en 
                      este array asociativo se alamacena la información del producto que se ha guardado en el carrito 
                      de compras. mediante la recepción de datos con la variable super global "$_POST". 
                   
                   4. Seguidamente se utiliza la variable super global "$_SESSION['carrtio']" en donde alamacenarán dichos 
                      productos desde la posición 0, almacenado el producto seleccionado conjuntamente con sus características. 
                      
                       
                       DENTRO DEL ELSE:
                       

                    5. De otra forma si la variable super global $_SESSION['carrito'], existe depositaremos más productos en el 
                       carrito de compras, para ello se declará una variable desde la cual se contabilizan los productos alamacenados 
                       en el carrito de compras, seguidamente se contabilizan los productos con la función "count()" en la cual se establece
                       como parámetro la super global "$_SESSION['carrito']"; desde donde so cuentas dichos productos.
                       
                    6. De la misma manera establecemos el array "$productsBuy" en donde se almacenan todas la carcteristicas del producto.
                    
                    7. Usamos nuevamente la variable super global "$_SESSION['carrito']"; en donde almacenaremos el número de productos, 
                       utilizando como posición inicial la variable que contabiliza loss productos, en este caso "$numberProducts". 

                       

                */

                 if(!isset($_SESSION['CARRITO'])){
                            $product=array(
                                'IMAGE_PRODUCT' =>$image_item,
                                'ID' =>$id_item,
                                'DATA_BUY' => $date_item,
                                'NAME_PRODUCT' =>$name_item,
                                'PRICE' =>$price_item ,
                                'QUANTITY' =>$quantity_item
                            );

                       $_SESSION['CARRITO'][0]=$product;
                       $message.= "Producto agregado al carrito";

                 }else{
                     /*Las lineas de código que se muestran a continuación especifican la no repetición 
                       de productos en el carrito (agregar dos productos iguales) de compras, en donde 
                       se describe lo siguiente:
                       
                       1. Se declara una variable que almacena la función "array_column()" esta función va
                          a almacenar todos los id de los productos que están en la variable de sesión
                          "$_SESSION['CARRITO']".
                      
                       2. En la condicional "if" se emplea la función "in_array()", que especifica cuantos si existe
                          un valor en ese array;     
                         
                       */ 
                     $idDisc = array_column($_SESSION['CARRITO'],"ID");   
                      if(in_array($id_item, $idDisc)){
                          $message.= "Este producto ya ha sido seleccionado.";
                      }else{

                       $numberProducts=count($_SESSION['CARRITO']);
                            $product=array(
                                'IMAGE_PRODUCT' =>$image_item,
                                'ID' =>$id_item,
                                'DATA_BUY' => $date_item,
                                'NAME_PRODUCT' =>$name_item,
                                'PRICE' =>$price_item ,
                                'QUANTITY' =>$quantity_item
                            );


                       $_SESSION['CARRITO'][$numberProducts]=$product;
                       $message.= "Producto agregado al carrito";

                     }       
                 }

                 //$message.= print_r($_SESSION,true);


               break; 
                 
               /*||||||||||||| ELIMINAR PRODUCTOS DEL CARRITO DE COMPRA |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||*/ 

               case 'Eliminar':
                  
                  if(is_numeric(openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY))){
                     $id_item = openssl_decrypt($_POST['id'],COD,KEY);

                  
                     foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $index=>$product){
                         if($product['ID'] == $id_item ){
                             unset($_SESSION['CARRITO'][$index]);
                                 echo $message.="Has elininado un producto!";
                         }
                     } 

                  }else{
                        $message.= "Uppss, id incorrecto..." . $id_item;
                  }

               break;   
         }

      }

?>
```

Este bloque de código corresponde al proceso de pago insertando los datos en las tablas "mi_pedido" y "carrito_compra"

```
<?php
   include('globals/config.php'); 
   include('globals/connect_data_base.php');
   include('carrito.php');

   if(!isset($_SESSION['userBuy'])){
     header('Location: form_login.php');
   }

   //error_reporting(0);

?>

<?php include('api/navbar_menu.php'); ?>
    
    <div class="process_payment_content">
     <!-- recepcionando datos del formulario de compra  --> 

<?php
       /* En el bloque de código que se muestra a continuaación se emplea la ssiguiente lógica:
          
          1. Se declara una condicional en donde se verificará si se ha estaablecido la variable 
             superglobal "$_POST", se dará paso a la inserción de datos en las tablas "carrito_compra"
             y "mi_pedido".
       */
      
       
      if($_POST){ 

           header("Location:form_login.php"); // Ojo: aqui debe de ir la redirección al formulario de registro.
   
           $total = 0;
           $sessionID = session_id();
           $emailTest=$_POST['email_shopping'];
           $userPayment=$_POST['payment_methods'];
           $userDelivery = $_POST['courier_methods'];
           
           /*-- Establecer la fecha de compra y la fecha de entrega --*/
           $dateBuy = date("Y-m-d");
           $dateBuyPickUp = date("Y-m-d",(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+2, date("Y"))));

           /*De la misma manera que se han contabilizado los datos en la tabla de productos del carrito de compra,
            se contabilizan los mismos datos de la compra, pero esta vez en el aparatdo de laa orden de compra
           */

            foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $index=>$product){
 
               /*-- TABLA MI_PEDIDO --*/
               $query_sentence = $pdo_connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `mi_pedido` (`id_pedido`, `id_usuario`, `email_usuarios`, `fecha_pedido`, `fecha_entrega`, `articulo`, `cantidad`, `precio`, `total`, `tipo_de_pago`, `tipo_de_envio`) 
               VALUES (NULL, :id_usuario, :emailUsuarios, :fehcaPedido, :fehcaEntrega, :name_product, :product_quantity, :product_price, :total, :buyType, :deliveryType)");

               $query_sentence->bindParam(":id_usuario", $sessionID);  
               $query_sentence->bindParam(":emailUsuarios", $emailTest);
               $query_sentence->bindParam(":fehcaPedido", $dateBuy);
               $query_sentence->bindParam(":fehcaEntrega", $dateBuyPickUp);
               $query_sentence->bindParam(":name_product", $product['NAME_PRODUCT']);
               $query_sentence->bindParam(":product_quantity", $product['QUANTITY']); 
               $query_sentence->bindParam(":product_price", $product['PRICE']);                                      
               $query_sentence->bindParam(":buyType", $userPayment);                                      
               $query_sentence->bindParam(":deliveryType", $userDelivery);                                      
               $query_sentence->bindParam(":total", $total);                                         
               $query_sentence->execute();
               $idBuy = $pdo_connect->lastInsertId();     
   
                  
               $total=$total+($product['PRICE']*$product['QUANTITY']);
            
            }
             
            foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $index=>$product){
             
               /*-- TABLA CARRITO_COMPRA --*/  
              $query_sentence = $pdo_connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `carrito_compra` (`id_registro`, `id_productos`, `id_usuarios`, `Directory_image`, `Articulo`, `Referencia`, `Cantidad`, `Precio`) 
                                                      VALUES (NULL, :id_producto, :id_usuario, :image_product, :name_product, '', :product_quantity, :product_price)");

              $query_sentence->bindParam(":id_usuario", $sessionID);                                      
              $query_sentence->bindParam(":id_producto", $product['ID']);                                      
              $query_sentence->bindParam(":image_product",  $product['IMAGE_PRODUCT']);
              $query_sentence->bindParam(":name_product", $product['NAME_PRODUCT']);                                      
              $query_sentence->bindParam(":product_price", $product['PRICE']);                                      
              $query_sentence->bindParam(":product_quantity", $product['QUANTITY']);                                       
              $query_sentence->execute(); 

            }

      }    
?>

<?php  
      if(!isset($_POST['addSubmit'])){
               echo "<div class='order_empty'><h2>No tienes ninguna orden  de compra.</h2></div>"; 
      }else{
          
      /*|||||||||||||||||||||| OJO: AQUI PROBABLEMENTE ES DONDE ESTE EL PROBLEMA ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||*/
      /* Se debe de crear un lógica la cual recepcione el id de usuario - y los productos guardados con su respectiva 
      sesión y su respectivo id */

      $idUserLogin=$_POST['id_usuarios'];
        $idReadClient = $pdo_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `id_usuarios`= $idUserLogin");
           $idReadClient->execute();
             $idRead=$idReadClient->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


?>  
     
      <div class="message_endpayment">
         <h1>¡Gracias por tu compra <?php echo $_SESSION['userBuy']; ?>!</h1>
         <p>Tu orden de compra es la siguiente:</p>
           
               <div class="order_titular">
                   <span>Fecha pedido</span>
                   <span>Fecha de entrega</span>
                   <span>Artículo</span>
                   <span>Cantidad</span>
                   <span>Precio</span>
                   <span>Tipo de Pago</span>
                   <span>tipo de Envío</span>
               </div>
          
           <div class="order_detail">

           <?php  
          
              $query_sentence = $pdo_connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mi_pedido`");
              $query_sentence->execute();
              $productsList = $query_sentence->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              
               foreach($productsList as $product){  ?>

                <div class="order_container">
                     <div class="order_item"> <?php echo $product['fecha_pedido']; ?> </div>
                     <div class="order_item"> <?php echo $product['fecha_entrega']; ?> </div>
                     <div class="order_item"> <?php echo $product['articulo']; ?> </div>
                     <div class="order_item"> <?php echo $product['cantidad']; ?> </div>
                     <div class="order_item"> <?php echo $product['precio'] . " €"; ?> </div>
                     <div class="order_item"> <?php echo $product['tipo_de_pago']; ?> </div>
                     <div class="order_item"> <?php echo $product['tipo_de_envio']; ?> </div>
                </div>

             <?php }?>
             </div>

         <h2>Por un total de: <?php echo number_format($total,2) . " €"; ?></h2>
         
          <p>Los productos serán enviados una vez efectuado el pago.</p>
          <strong>Para cualquier duda o consulta escribenos a: info_music@extrememusic.com</strong>

      </div>
    
<?php }?> 


     </div>  
     <?php include('formulario_registro.php'); ?>
     <!-- footer content -->
     <?php include('api/navbar_footer.php'); ?>
```

Espero esté lo suficientemente legible el código, dejo claro que soy principiante en el desarrollo con PHP

Saludos y gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Recuerda que aquí los problemas son acerca de _programación_. Edita tu pregunta para hacer referencia a un problema _específico_, mostrando un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: no has realizado ningun script para poder guiarnos a ayudarte?¿ igualmente lo que te pide lo puedes hacer con localStorage en JS

Comment: Hola, lo añadiré a la brevedad posible. 

Saludos.